# Different QTextEdit line height on Mac and Windows

Tags: macos, qt, layout, fonts, qtextedit

I am developing a text editor application based on QTextEdit/QGraphicsTextItem and noticed that the results of QTextEdit on Windows are different to the ones on Mac.

Specifically, when testing with a multi line text snippet in the "Text Edit" sample of Qt 4.8.5:

- When using large font sizes (48pt) the text layout is pretty much identical
- When using small font sizes (8pt) the text snippet has a noticeably larger height on Windows

I've found a couple of related StackOverflow questions but didn't find a suitable answer in them. Thus I tried to dig deeper and figured out the following:

- Font size 48pt: the line height on Mac and Windows are very close to each other (both about 60%)
- Font size 8pt: the line height on Mac is about 50%. On Windows it is about 75%

When referring to "line height" I compared the ascent height (i.e. height of "T") against the height between them (between two text lines).

Here is a screenshot showing the problem. The red lines are the base lines of the Mac text lines.:

[image: Mac/Windows Line Height Comparison]

It seems that the line height causes the text layout to be different on Mac and Windows. Is there any way in Qt to enforce an identical text layout on Mac and Windows (Microsoft Word manages to do so)? Or does anybody have other suggestions about this?

Comment: Is this a difference between native applications as well? For example, Notepad vs the Mac equivalent, would they have the same difference if the font was the same? Maybe it's just that the OSes have different font-rendering conventions, and Qt is trying to look native in Mac.

Comment: One option would be to check if QPlainTextEdit behaves differently, and if it does nto and can suite your needs, it might be alternative solution

Comment: @sashoalm: I don't think comparing Microsoft Wordpad against Apples TextEdit makes sense. They have a different code base and might use different font metrics/rendering code. I compared Microsoft Word on Win7 and MacOS, and they are very close to each other (not 100% identical, but close enough).

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: QPlainText does not support rich text formatting, right (bold, italic, numbered lists, ...)? In that case it unfortunately wouldn't be an alternative for my application.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a fix for this problem, thus can't really mark an answer as solution here. Actually it simply looks like the text layout isn't guaranteed to be identical across platforms in Qt.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, Qt 4.8 in Mac uses system rendering engine & Windows and other platform uses Harfbuzz. Qt 5.X uses Qt Harfbuzz for all platforms.   Two different rendering engine not likely to have same rendering out put. Try with Qt 5.2 if you can.

Comment: Very good point, I didn't know about that. I did did a test port of the application to Qt 5.2. The text layout is different to Qt 4.8 in some cases, but it still differs very much from the Windows version. Still, was worth a try. Btw: it seems to be possible to enable HarfBuzz for Mac also in 4.8: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17728